# Splitting a line and filling an array skipping blank values in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array of line, which is somewhat like below

Here's example:

```
A-NUMBER                      ROUTINF   ACO   AO    L    MISCELL

0-0                                     0           1-20
0-00
0-01                             FDS                3-20
0-02                                    6      7    3-20
0-03                                           4    3-20
1-0                                                      F=PRE
                                                         ANT=3
                                                         NAPI=1
1-1                                                      F=PRE
                                                         ANT=3
```

I need to parse the line according to column by skipping the column which has blank values and create a new line like below

```
ANUM = 0-0, ACO=0, L=1-20;
ANUM = 0-00;
ANUM = 0-01, ROUTINF=FDS, L=3-20;
ANUM = 0-02, ACO=6, AO=7, L=3-20;
ANUM = 0-03, AO=4,L=3-20;
ANUM = 1-0, F=PRE, ANT=3, NAPI=1;
ANUM = 1-1, F=PRE, ANT=3;
```

I can split the line but my code can't remember which column the value belongs to and when to skip the values.

```
String[] splitted = null;
for (Integer i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
        splitted = lines.get(i).split("\\s+");
        for(String str : splitted)
        if(!(splitted.length == 1)){
                anum = splitted[0];
                routinf = splitted[1];
                aco = splitted[2];
                ao = splitted[3];
                l = splitted[4];
         }else {
                miscell = splitted[0];
            }        
         }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The columns in your file seems to be of fixed length (I don't see any other way to distinguish each column). If that is the case then I would recommend using `substring(srat, end)` instead of `split`.

Create a class to hold one single record.

```
class Record {
    String aNumber,
    List<String> routingf, aco, ao, l, miscell;

    public Record(String aNumber) {
        this.aNumber = aNumber;
        this.routingf = new ArrayList<>();
        // init other lists like above ...
    }

    public void addRoutingf(String routingf) {
        // add only of not null and is not empty trimmed
        if(routingf != null && routiingf.trim().length() > 0) {
            this.routingf.add(routiingf);
        }
    }

    // implement add-methods for other lists like above ...
}
```

While parsing each line remember the last created record. If in the actual line `A-NUMBER` is empty then use the last created record to store the values, otherwise create a new record and remember it as last/actual so you can use it for the upcoming lines if necessary.

Save all record in a list

```
List<Record> records = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: thanks, i think i can find the column length from header and split each string. thanks for the clue.

Comment: as i am an amateur, can you tell me how to add strings to Records?

Comment: @user3131745 thank you too sir :D . If this answer could help you then you might want to mark it as accepted and probably up-vote it as well ;-). PS: As you are going to implement that `not null` and `not empty` check for all your method it would be better to extract that line of code in an own method `boolean isNotNullOrEmtyTrimed(String s) { return s != null && s.trim().length() > 0; }`

Answer (score 0):

What is the common separator? Just split on that... Your + at the moment will consume any amount of white space. \s{1,4} wil limit it to between 1 and 4 characters. Find the right numbers for your data.

Comment: common separator is spaces. i think of using substring with column header for start,end value

Answer (score 0):

if your input time use one space char (for instance tab) between columns your code is almost OK

```
String[] splitted = null;
for (Integer i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
    splitted = lines.get(i).split("\\s");
    if(!(splitted.length == 1)){
            anum = splitted[0];
            routinf = splitted[1];
            aco = splitted[2];
            ao = splitted[3];
            l = splitted[4];
     }else {
            miscell = splitted[0];
        }        
     }
     //print only not empty fields
```

pls note removing of unnecessary for loop and change of split character to \s from \s+

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, but you could also experiment if it helps to keep the whitespaces in the result for defining which column it belongs to.

```
lines.get(i).split(yourDelimiter, -1);
```

Its hard to tell if this helps without knowing what exactly your origin files are looking like, but you could give it a try.

e.g. if the values are always at a certain point in the splitted string with whitespaces, you could easily tell which column it belongs to and extract them.